# OS X: Is there an open source screen recorder?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, screen-capture

I need a screen recorder. However, I try to avoid using closed-source software whenever possible except from major vendors like Apple and Skype.

I am wondering, is there an open source screen recorder for Mac OS X?

Or if not, does Apple include such a thing with the OS? Or how about using Skype? I'm running Snow Leopard.

Comment: Try and answer some other questions and once you have the reputation, you can answer your own questions. You could also flag your comment and see if a moderator can move it to an answer. I'm not sure they can do that, but it shouldn't hurt to try...

Comment: @Mithras May I ask why you've edited your question to remove the parts that make it specific to screen recording? The question is now extremely vague...

Answer (score 8):

You've answered your own question, but I thought I would flesh it out a bit.

You are correct that QuickTime will record a window, or the whole screen, but it only does so with the version of QT that ships with Lion. It wasn't available in earlier versions of QT or OS X (I'm not sure if the latest QT would do this on an older OS - I don't have one to try it on.)

I was pleasantly surprised to see that it now had that functionality - there really aren't any other free or low cost options.

Comment: QuickTime in Snow Leopard also recorded the screen

Answer (score 8):

[Kap is a great option.](https://github.com/wulkano/kap) Recently (January 3, 2017) they hit version 1.0.0.

Its great features include:

- Export to Gif, WebM, MP4
- Audio recording
- Hiding the mouse cursor and highlighting clicks
- Record a portion of your screen with a custom size and aspect ratio
- "High" FPS recording

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) is an open source media player which also offers screen capture facilities (via File -> Open Capture Device..).

Comment: This only gives the option for the FaceTime camera. What version of VLC are you using?

Comment: It looks like the feature was removed at some point in the last year. I'd suggest Quicktime's built-in screen recording feature. See "Record your screen" on [this Apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4024).

Comment: @AlexGittemeier, You need to select `Screen` for the dropdown where `Input Devices` is showing.

Answer (score 1):

[Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com) may be a reasonable option. The project [appears to be open source](https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio) and to support macOS:

> ### [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com)
>
> Free and open source software for video recording and live streaming. Download and start streaming quickly and easily on Windows, Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

### Open Source

- [jScreenRecorder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jscreenrecorder/) GPL, java-based screen recorder.
- [VLC](http://www.wikihow.com/Screen-Capture-to-File-Using-VLC) has this as a feature and it's great for playback, streaming and transcoding.
- [Capture Me](http://download.cnet.com/Capture-Me/3000-2192_4-10302571.html)

### Closed Source

- [Jing](https://www.techsmith.com/jing-features.html) is great for making screencasts and taking screenshots. There's a free version that does the job fine.
- QuickTime is capable and it comes with OS X.
- [IShowUHD](http://www.shinywhitebox.com/ishowu-hd-pro)

Comment: Which of these are open source?

Comment: non cnet link, please? uBlock even warned me about it.